# Reading specific content from a web page?

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to make an app (in C#) in which I have to get some meanings from a website like wiktionary.com or dictionary.com. But I have never used Xml or worked with web pages at all.

I managed to get the response from the webpage (e.g from dictionary.com for a specific word) (which I hope is the xml format).

This is what I got for the word 'Hello'.:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Strict//EN">
<!--attributes for answers reference-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<head>
<title>
Hello | Define Hello at Dictionary.com
</title>
<meta name="description" content="Hello definition, (used to express a greeting, answer a telephone, or attract attention.) See more."/>
<meta name="keywords" content="hello, online dictionary, English dictionary, hello definition, define hello, definition of hello, hello pronunciation, hello meaning, hello origin, hello examples"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hello"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="the definition of hello"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Dictionary.com"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://sp2.dictionary.com/en/i/dictionary/facebook/dictionary_logo.png"/>
```

Now I want to parse the following string out of the response.

```
used to express a greeting, answer a telephone, or attract attention.
```

I tried using XmlReader but got stuck. Can somebody please help me read this content?

Comment: Be careful with screen scraping if that's what you're doing. A lot of times it violates the terms and conditions for the website, and your implementation will also be tightly coupled with their html format. If they change their site, a lot of times your code will no longer work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily parse HTML with [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
// replace with your own content
doc.Load("file.htm");
foreach(HtmlNode meta in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/meta[@name='description'"])
{
    HtmlAttribute att = meta["content"];
    Consol.WriteLine( att.Value );
}
```

Comment: His response is XHTML (see headers), so an XML parser will work fine.

Comment: According to doctype, it's html. But you're right : Xml parser will work fine, according html is perfecly formed, with proper tag closing, and no funky chars (for example)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can you also tell how to use XML parser here? Since I am trying to learn the use of XML as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a web services like http://services.aonaware.com/, it's much more better for you and for the targeting web site :-).

http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php is another option which has a much simpler API